# SQLiteDatabase Running in android

Tags: android, sqlite

[image]Hey i am trying to build an app, where i am inserting values into a Database, and trying to retrieve records using 4 methods.
Methods : `movetoFirst(), moveToLast(), moveToNext(), moveToPrevious()`.
Method 1 and 2 are executing properly. But i am Facing a problem for next and previous method. The following is the code i amm attaching for the above query.

Declaration.

```
package com.Rohit.taskforsqllite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText e1, e2, e3;
Cursor c;
SQLiteDatabase db;
int count;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcount);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("Listname", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("create table if not exists list1(name varchar,location varchar,      phone number)");
    // Insert values into table
    db.execSQL("insert into list1 values('Rohit','London',12)");
    db.execSQL("insert into list1 values('Raj','Hyd',23)");
    db.execSQL("insert into list1 values('PRak','Canada',34)");
    db.execSQL("insert into list1 values('Sanj','Mad',45)");
    db.execSQL("insert into list1 values('Anna','Polland',56)");

    c = db.rawQuery("select * from list1", null);

    count = c.getCount();`import android.app.Activity;
```

Method 1;

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            c.moveToFirst();

            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String location = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("location")));
            String phone = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("phone")));

            e1.setText(name);
            e2.setText(location);
            e3.setText(phone);
            Log.d("Record from db", name + "," + location + "," + phone);

        }
    });
```

Method 2:

```
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishbuton);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // c = db.rawQuery("select * from list1", null);
            c.moveToLast();

            String name = c.getString(0);
            String location = c.getString(1);
            String phone = c.getString(2);

            e1.setText(name);
            e2.setText(location);
            e3.setText(phone);
            Log.d("Record from db", name + "," + location + "," + phone);

        }
    });
```

Method 3. This is where i amm facing the problem, if i try to execute using while loop. Its going to execute upto the end of the loop. But i don't want to do that, i want to display one record at a time when i press previous button.

```
Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousbutton);

    b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (c.moveToFirstt()) {
                do {
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    String location = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex("location"));
                    String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone"));
                    e1.setText(name);
                    e2.setText(location);
                    e3.setText(phone);
                    Log.d("Record from db", name + "," + location + ","
                            + phone);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: while (c.moveToPrevious());

Answer (score 1):

if you use moveToLast() then you must move to previous row and use c.moveToPrevious, no c.moveToNext()

Comment: Sorrys its moveToFirst not last. But when you try to do moveToLast, you going to use c.moveToPrevious. But its not going to change anything in the execution. AS we are using while loop, it executes end of the loop. So, we gonna end at c.getString(0). But what im willing try ova here is , get the position of the object and use moveToPrevious. So, the data will move to next column one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you understand using Cursor properly. Read documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) please.

When you use moveToLast(), its to be expected that you only loop through 1 row...

The proper construct to loop through results is the following:

```
while(c.moveToNext()) {
  //... fetch data from current row
}
```